# Any interceptors or Listeners for JPARepository / CrudRepository methods of Spring boot data JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, interceptor, event-listener

I want to do the logging with additional messages on all database method calls from `JPARepository` `CrudRepository` or `Repository`. All methods like findByxxx, save, delete, etc should be intercepted or listened.

There is way to inject Hibernate interceptor with the following:

`hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.interceptor", jpaRepositoryInterceptor);`

I am not sure if this works with all `Repository` find methods. I am wondering if there are alternative / better ways to do that. Goal is to not update any entities or repositories that are existing. I should be able to apply the logging without needing to udpate.

Comment: Not sure if AOP AspectJ would be handy?

Comment: No. AOP would not work for me. I need the Entity details